# print array from arrayList in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i am trying to print arrayList but i am getting something like this.

> [[Ljava.lang.String;@506c589e, [Ljava.lang.String;@69d0a921,
>   [Ljava.lang.String;@446cdf90]

I also tried but no result.

> Arrays.toString(list.get(0))

Please help.

```
public ArrayList getByName(String name) {
    try {
        preSt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE name=?");
        preSt.setString(1, name);
        rs = preSt.executeQuery();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            Object[] temp = new String[3];
            temp[0] = rs.getString("name");
            temp[1] = rs.getString("surname");
            temp[2] = rs.getString("age");
            list.add(i, temp);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        return list;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to print that list is to iterate through it.  Remember that each element of that list is itself an array, so you'll need `Arrays.toString` to print it.

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

// populate it in here

for(Object[] array : list) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Comment: I tried to run this code when list is returned here is a code which gets it.
`code` public void getNew(List name) {
        for(Object[] array : name) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
    }
i get error like this 
`code` Error:(15, 30) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[]

Comment: That error would only happen if you didn't change the declaration of `list`, like I've shown on the first line of code in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are already working with arrays, you may consider this method which will allow you to avoid writing a hand-coded loop:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(list.toArray()));
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works too. but i needed to print out arrays separately.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
public ArrayList getByName(String name) {
    try {
        preSt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE name=?");
        preSt.setString(1, name);
        rs = preSt.executeQuery();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            Object[] temp = new String[3];
            temp[0] = rs.getString("name");
            temp[1] = rs.getString("surname");
            temp[2] = rs.getString("age");
            list.add(i, temp);
            i++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
        return list;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i tried this one and gor err like this
Error:(63, 40) java: array required, but java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object> found

Comment: This won't fix the problem.  Did you actually try it?

Comment: `list` is an `ArrayList`. You can't access elements using `[]` like an array.

Comment: Then u can you map instead of list.Because you are adding twom paramter so go with map like this

Comment: Map<int,object> map = new HashMap<int,object>();